# C# Expression trees - combine multiple method calls

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, expression-trees

I'm using .Net Core and expression trees.

I have a Product class, where LstProp property contains list of values separated by ';', like "val1;val2;val3;":

```
public class Product
{
  // actually contains list of values separated by ';'
  public string LstProp{get; set;}
}
```

And I want to filter Products by this property and contains any condition using expression trees.
I've try this, but it doesn't work.

```
 var value="val1;val2"
 var productItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "product");
 var prop = Expression.Property(productItem, "LstProp");

 MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
 var values = value.ToString().Split(';');
 Expression predicate = null;
 foreach (var val in values)
 {
    var listPropExpression = Expression.Constant(val);
    var containsExpresion=Expression.Call(listPropExpression, method, property);
    predicate = predicate != null ? Expression.Or(predicate, containsExpresion) : containsExpresion;
 }
```

So I'm trying to combine call  of Contains function for each value in the list, but getting error about "No conversion between BinaryExpression and MethodCallExpression".

How could I combine multiple method calls with expression trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.
I got two problems:

1. Incorrect order of parameters.
   Should be `Expression.Call(property, method, listPropExpression);` instead `Expression.Call(listPropExpression, method, property);`
2. Main problem was solved with simple cast:

   predicate = predicate != null ? (Expression) Expression.Or(predicate, containsExpresion) : containsExpresion;

As a Result I get expression like `product=>product.LstProp.Contains("val1") Or product.LstProp.Contains("val2")`